# Numpy np.array with dtype TypeError

Tags: python, numpy

**Description**

I have spent about an hour trying to hunt down a numpy array construction error. I must not be using numpy dtypes correctly but the error message is not descriptive enough and I am not given a good enough stack trace to find the error.

**Simplified Example that creates same error**:

```
 import numpy as np
 names = ['id', 'x']
 formats = [np.int64, np.float64]
 np.array([1, 1.0], dtype={'names': names, 'formats': formats})
```

The following code results in the error

```
 ----> 1 np.array([1, 1.0], dtype={'names': names, 'formats': formats})
 TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'int'
```

So i get that the error occurs from the first element being an int but why is it expecting a bytes like object?

Answer: it has nothing to do with the fact that the first element is in int. The list needs to be a tuple see below.

Comment: uh, what exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: Trying to construct a record array figured out the solution and it is not at all obvious. Numpy need to fix this.

Answer (score 5):

The solution is that numpy requires a single tuple or list of tuples. **Not** a list of lists or list.

The following works

```
 np.array((1, 1.0), dtype={'names': names, 'formats': formats})
```

I find it frustrating that numpy gives no indication in the error that this is what is expected.

Comment: That requirement isn't as explicit on this docs page as it could be: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html.  There is also an example without commentary in docs for `np.array`: `x = np.array([(1,2),(3,4)],dtype=[('a','<i4'),('b','<i4')])`